# How to handle scaling upto 3k concurrent connections

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, phpmyadmin, scaling

So here's our use case:
We have firmware that connects to server (simple php file - that takes post request) and add the data (350-500 bytes per request) to database.

Now here's a issue we have 3k units in the market and non-technical manager wants server to be able to handle 3k concurrent connections in worst case. Current it can handle around 600-650 connections (VPS 8GB NVMe - 6 core CPU (3.1 GHz) - 8GB NVMe RAM - 100GB NVMe SSD and 4TB bandwidth) costs around $100/month.

To scale up/scale out the cost is going to be enormous especially in the future when they are expecting 100k-500k units (which will again be a worst case).

Now good thing is that even if firmware fails to connect to server it can try reconnecting after 1 min/3 min and so on.. until the data is pushed - doesn't really hinders user experience at all. That's what I have been trying to convince them to do. Any other tips?

And let's say if we were to scale to that level what would be server I should look into.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: When you are ready to boost capacity of your existing equipment, please post info requested a couple days ago.  With information available to analyze, we can reduce your present system overhead with performance tuning of your Global Variables.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: "concurrent connections" is not a good metric.  Better:  "queries per second".  Almost any machine can handle hundreds of qps if they come from a combination of connections.